# How to remove and unlink multiple images in json format

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have multiple images saved in database like this.

```
["7541556437392.JPG","9741556437392.JPG"]
```

[image]

I try to pass json decode and the image parameter that store in database but I get an error with message

> Array to string conversion

my delete controller

```
public function forceDestroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
    $post->tags()->detach(); //tag
    $post ->forceDelete();

    $this->removeImage(json_decode($post->image,true));

    Alert::success('Your post has been deleted successfully')->persistent('Close');

    return redirect('admins-blogpost?status=trash');
}
```

my remove image method, I try to unlink image and image thumbnail together when delete the post related to them.

```
public function removeImage($image)
{
    if( ! empty($image))
    {
        $imagePath = $this->uploadPath . '/' . $image;
        $ext = substr(strrchr($image, '.'), 1);
        $thumbnail = str_replace(".{$ext}", "_thumb.{$ext}", $image);
        $thumbnailPath = $this->uploadPath . '/' . $thumbnail;
        if(file_exists($imagePath) ) unlink($imagePath);
        if(file_exists($thumbnailPath) ) unlink($thumbnailPath);
    }
}
```

I want to delete all images when delete the post related to images that. How to fix my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your JSON represents an array, you need to iterate over its elements. Try this:

```
foreach (json_decode($post->image, true) as $image) {
    $this->removeImage($image);
}
```

Comment: thanks it is working for delete post. 

can you help me for remove image when i update new image.
i try your ways but can't delete oldImage.

Comment: i try to update and remove but not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55889217/how-to-update-and-remove-multiple-old-images-in-json

Comment: @IlhamFirmanAshari the answer you got to that question looks like it should work.