# how to update and remove (unlink) multiple old images in json format

Tags: php, json, laravel

this is still related to my post in here [How to remove and unlink multiple images in json format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55888883/how-to-remove-and-unlink-multiple-images-in-json-format)

i can store and delete all multiple images. but i have still problem when update and remove old image. my code still not remove the oldimage when update the new image.

my update controller, i use handlerequest method to store images, where oldImage is variable in database that will be compared with new images. if not same then remove old images.

```
public function update(Requests\UpdatePostRequest $request, $id)
{

    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $oldImage = $post->image;
    $data = $this->handleRequest($request);
    $post->update($data);


    if($oldImage != $post->image)
    {
        foreach (json_decode($post->image, true) as $oldImage) {
        $this->removeImage($oldImage);
        }
    }

    if($request->submitbutton =='Publish')
    {
        Alert::success('Your post was updated successfully')->persistent('Close');
        return redirect(route('admins-blogpost.index'));
    }
    if($request->submitbutton =='Save Draft')
    {
        Alert::success('Your draft was updated successfully')->persistent('Close');
        return redirect(route('admins-blogpost.index'));
    }
}
```

my handlerequest method to store multiple image, this method is working using store method. so this problem not here.

```
private function handleRequest($request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $images = $request->file('image');
        foreach($images as $key=>$image){
            $fileName    = $image->getClientOriginalName();

            $destination = $this->uploadPath;

            $successUploaded = $image->move($destination, $fileName);
            if($successUploaded)
            {
                $width = config('cms_blog.image.thumbnail.width');
                $height = config('cms_blog.image.thumbnail.height');
                $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $thumbnail = str_replace(".{$extension}", "_thumb.{$extension}", $fileName);
                Image::make($destination . '/' . $fileName)
                        ->resize($width,$height)
                        ->save($destination . '/' . $thumbnail);
                $datax[] = $fileName;
            }
            $data['image'] = json_encode($datax);
        }

    }
    return $data;
}
```

and delete method

```
public function removeImage($image)
{
    if( ! empty($image))
    {
        $imagePath = $this->uploadPath . '/' . $image;
        $ext = substr(strrchr($image, '.'), 1);
        $thumbnail = str_replace(".{$ext}", "_thumb.{$ext}", $image);
        $thumbnailPath = $this->uploadPath . '/' . $thumbnail;
        if(file_exists($imagePath) ) unlink($imagePath);
        if(file_exists($thumbnailPath) ) unlink($thumbnailPath);
    }
}
```

how to fix my problem so i can remove old images when their not same with new image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the for loop where you delete the images, I believe you wanted to iterate over `$oldImage`, not over `$post->image`:

```
foreach (json_decode($oldImage, true) as $item) {
    $this->removeImage($item);
}
```

Comment: thanks. i'm not focused. yeah because of that, i can't remove the old image

Answer (score 0):

Storing multiple images name on a single column, which is not a good idea. I suggested you create another table post_images or something else.

And create hasMany relation from posts table with post_images table. Then you have lot's of flexibility here. Also, you can create a Polymorphic Relationship to use the same image model with multiple Models.

Comment: okay. thanks for your advice. you can share the information using link or something that can me learn.  in my brain, i need image id that store image related to my single post? if i need to show more image from one id then how, i need more image id? On another table, example **image table**, if one id store multiple name then it's same. i just add database table.